# How to pass HttpRequest/Reponse as parameter to function when function is called from Quartz scheduler?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I'm running spring-boot application, i have implemented the quartz scheduler as the part of the application.

Earlier I had a rest controller with end points such as http://localhost:8080/GoogleMail/{id} which triggers the function as shown below and accepts the HttpServletRequest/Response as the parameter along with the Pathvariable which i'm passing.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/GoogleMail/{id}", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public String sendMail(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @Valid @PathVariable(value = "id") String id,
            @Valid @RequestBody MailMessage mailMsg) throws Exception {
        if(id == null || id.isEmpty()) {
            ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }
        this.userId = id;

        return GoogleMailIntegrationService.sendUserMails(request, response, id, mailMsg,
                m -> !StringUtils.isBlank(mailMsg.getTo())
                && !StringUtils.isBlank(mailMsg.getSubject())
                && !StringUtils.isBlank(mailMsg.getBody()));
    }
```

Now instead of making the REST call, i need to call this function by posting JSON body for every 1 hour using the Quartz scheduler. May be as shown below

```
if (context.getJobDetail().getKey().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(JobName.READRESPONSE.toString())) {
           // emailService.readMail();
            try {
              sendMail(Request, Response, id);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My question : Is there a way to make REST call using Scheduler or is it possible to make sendMail() call by passing request/response params directly.

I'm not sure on how to do this, i spent most of my time browsing for the solution prior posting.

Comment: Are these controller & quartz scheduler in a separate applications?

Comment: No, both are in same application

Comment: Is there a reason why your scheduler could just not call `GoogleMailIntegrationService` directly? If you need it also in rest api you could just separate logic to separate function that both rest api & scheduler use?

Comment: It is not a good idea wait 1 hour to response a body, you might want first schedule the request so quartz has a listener that execute at the certain time, then that method called executeInternal I think you can create a webhook to send the response body .

Comment: GoogleMailIntegrationService requires HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response to work with authenication, how can i pass this if i directly use GoogleMailIntegrationService?

Comment: @JonathanJohx I just gave an example as one hour. In the actual scenario, SendMail function might trigger once in a day to send mails to end customers

Comment: @coders I am sorry, I don't get your question so.

Comment: @JonathanJohx Everyday, quartz will trigger a function call where i need call, sendMail function which requires Request/Response as the parameters to work. If i make function from quartz trigger, how can i pass httprequest/response as a parameter? Is my question

Comment: So your question is more like howto instantiate request/response because those are interfaces?

Comment: I got it , then you can create a RestTemplate and call the post controller, ResponseEntity<String> responseEntityStr = restTemplate.
      postForEntity("http://localhost/GoogleMail/{someId}", "id", String.class); @coders if you want a full answer on this, I might create it.

Comment: @pirho yes, you got it

Comment: @JonathanJohx Ok please post the complete answer. If i do like this, doesn't it requires cookie to be set insorder to make a call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **RestTemplate** in order to do a request call to some controller endpoint by following way:

```
if (context.getJobDetail().getKey().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(JobName.READRESPONSE.toString())) {
     // emailService.readMail();
     try {
         RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
         HttpEntity<MailMessage > request = new HttpEntity<>(mailMsg, new HttpHeaders());

         ResponseEntity<String> responseEntityStr = 
             restTemplate.postForEntity(
             String.format("http://localhost:7777/GoogleMail/%s", id), 
             request, String.class);

     } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can we pass body?

Comment: the body is the request, HttpEntity I put the MailMessage, you should add maildMsg as object with values as well.

Comment: ooh ok. Thanks. I will check this out

Comment: How to make GET Entity call ? Could you please let me know?

Comment: Sure, you can take a look this link https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Comment: Thanks you for pointing me out in the right direction. Let me check and get back to you

Comment: It's throwing 403 error. Since the end point is not accessible by everyone, i need to take session from cookie. Any idea on how to get this?

Comment: If you need to add something on some header you should add `new HttpHeaders()` key and values if you need to authenticate as well. perhaps API key or something like that.